# For what set of functions is $f$, defined on the interval $[-1,1]$ such that $f(0) = a$, a linear space?

Tags: linear-algebra

> For what set of functions $f(x)$ defined on the interval $[-1,1]$ and such that $f(0) = a$, is a linear space?

If $8$ axioms of a linear space are satisfied, then it is a linear space. I do not understand how to choose $a$. If $a$ are values How can I count their? Explain, please.

Comment: If $f$ continious/real valued/complex valued? Somehow I miss information.

Comment: Necessary and sufficient condition $a=0$.

Comment: I think values are real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the set $F_a:=\{f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}~:~f(0)=a\}$. If $F_a$ is a linear space, then $f,g\in F_a$ implies $f+g\in F_a$. Now you can check this.

Solution:

> If $f,g\in F_a$, then $f(0)=a=g(0)$ and $(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)=a+a=2a$. You see that $f+g\in F_a$ if and only if $2a=a$ if and only if $a=0$.
>
> So if $F_a$ is a linear space, then $a=0$ is necessary. On the other hand, if $a\neq 0$, then $f+g\notin F_a$ and $F_a$ is not a linear space.
>
> You have still to check, that $F_0$ is a linear space. That should be no problem.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, To determine this, you introduced one more function?

Comment: I didn't introduced a function, just the set $F_a$ of the functions you described.

Comment: I understood. You took a value from [−1,1].

Comment: I edited the solution a bit. But I don't understand what you mean by "you took a value from $[-1,1]$". I used the property, that each function $f\in F_a$ holds $f(0)=a$ as assumed.

Comment: I would like to check that  F0 is a linear space, but i don't understand how can i do it, because i am kettle ( Seemingly, I understood why a = 0, but this i can't do.

Comment: That is really elementary. You have to check the axioms one by one and use that the addition and scalar multiplication of functions are pointwise defined. I.e. for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in F_0$ you have $(\lambda f+g)(x)=\lambda\cdot f(x)+g(x)$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, you have all properties you need.

Comment: What is Fo? How can i count it? I do not understand anything, do not tell me where you can read about this, please? i would like know it.

Comment: You seem to have basic problems in understanding the notation. $F_0$ is the set $F_a$ where $a=0$, which means $F_0=\{f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}~:~f(0)=0\}$.

Comment: Hence, F1 is the set Fa, where a = 1. Do I understand correctly? Thank you a lot that explain me.

Comment: Yes... $F_1=\{f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}~:~f(0)=1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the set is a linear space, then the function $f$ , defined by $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$, must belong to this set. Hence: $a=0$.